# Best way to safely navigate through JSON response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I need to navigate through a large JSON response, in which several attributes may or may not be present. I am aware of the following options to achieve this:

**Hash using dig**

```
a = JSON.parse(response)
a.dig(:user, :address, :street)
```

**OpenStruct using dig**

```
a = JSON.parse(response, object_class: OpenStruct)
a.dig(:user, :address, :street)
```

**OpenStruct using safe operator**

```
a = JSON.parse(response, object_class: OpenStruct)
a.user&.address&.street
```

Which of those options (if any) should I prefer?

Comment: If you use `.dig` there is no need to use `OpenStruct`.  `OpenStruct` is generally slower than a plain hash since all access goes through `method_missing`. You can use `ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess` instead.